# Screen does not ligh up on incoming call

Tags: calls, screen

Xperia Z5 Dual with Android 7.1.1

Sometimes when the device is receiving a phone call (Messenger and Whatsapp work fine), the screen does not light up and I am unable to pick up the call.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Custom or stock ROM? Maybe try to re-calibrate proximity sensor

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје curious: what does the proximity sensor have to do with the screen turning on *on incoming calls?* Viktor wouldn't notice that if the phone were at his ear, so most likely it is not. The sensor should just "toggle" the display while in-call, AFAIR, not when signaling an incoming call (end of second paragraph in the question).

Comment: @Izzy Yes I know that, you are completely right. But I had some bug where my phone won't wake up the screen but sound play and I can't answer call it was because proximity sensor was stuck on "near". But that was lg phone which proximity sensor was used not to unlock phone via knock on while in pocket. I' m not sure how proximity sensor works with other phones.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Ah, I see – yes, special circumstances. Thanks for the background details! Cannot hurt checking, sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-calibrating your proximity sensor.
You can also try wiping the top of screen, around the sensor location. Any coating can sometimes interfere with the normal operation of the sensor.

Comment: That was already recommended in a comment – and asked how it is related. AFAIK the proximity sensor is not involved at all for the display to turn on when an incoming call is detected.